# MongoDB not able to $unset particular field; automatic _id field at the end

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing code to manage a collection of merchants through a website using the plain MongoDB driver for NodeJS. My trouble occurs when the merchant is trying to confirm their account. It is expected for the code to use $unset to erase the value from database therefore activating the merchant's account. Instead, the query returns true, but the confirm field remains untouched. Here is an example of one of the problematic merchants in the database as printed by db.merchants.find({}) (with added line breaks for better readability):

```
{ "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "<hashed password is here>", 
  "salt" : "<salt is here>", "access" : "merchant",
  "created" : 1444000000000, "confirm" : "bKEQD0aiV8aXIQPY4CUxCm7KGSZ2pFJM",
  "name" : "Test user",
  "contact" : { "name" : "Test User", 
  "address" : "123 Cedar Ln N",
  "city" : "Some City", "state" : "AA",
  "zip" : "00000", "country" : "USA",
  "phone" : "5555555555" },
  "_id" : ObjectId("56133111d30ce5d4736323cb") }
```

AssumEffectively, this is the JS used in order to insert the item to the database:

```
db.collection("merchants").insert({
    name: "Test user",
    email: "test@test.com",
    .... more fields....,
    confirm: "bKEQD0aiV8aXIQPY4CUxCm7KGSZ2pFJM"
}, someCallback);
```

...and here is how I attempt to unset the "confirm" field:

```
db.collection("merchants").findOne({email: "test@test.com"}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) return handleError();
    if(!user) return sendFailureMessageToClient();
    if(client.confirm == user.confirm) {
        db.collection("merchants").update({_id: user.id},
            {$unset: {confirm: true}}, someCallback);
    }
}
```

I am certain that the update command above is actually being executed.

One of the things I think is interesting about the data above is that the _id field is at the end... is that supposed to normally happen? Would that mess up the $unset for the update command? If that is not the issue, then what is?

Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT: I showed why I am using a separate findOne request and then update.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is a special BSON object of ObjectId. Using the `id` string is not enough. You probably want to use `_id` as well:

```
db.collection("merchants").update({_id: ObjectId(user._id)},
```

You may also want to use `findAndModify` instead.

Comment: That does not seem to be helping... besides, I am pretty sure the user._id I use is already of type ObjectID.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the underscore in `user.id`, should be `user._id`. Right now, it's trying to fetch an user with `undefined` _id.

If it's not that, you should do your update on the email field, it'll work just fine (assuming it's unique).

The _id at the end of the document doesn't matter, there is no strict order in JSON/BSON fields. The only moment an order is maintened is inside arrays.